# How can one quantify the convergence of relative frequency to probability?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics, confidence-interval

I have a rather basic question about statistics but I am unable to find an answer in the literature I have at hand. Say I run a simple Bernoulli trial a number of times and compute the relative frequency for success. Clearly the relative frequency should represent the underlying probability for success better the more experiments I run.

My question is this: Is there any way to say how close the two values are given the number of times the experiment was run? For example if I run the experiment $N$ times, what is the expected deviation of the relative frequency and the probability? Or turning the question around: If I want to know the probability up to an uncertainty of $\varepsilon$, how many experiments do I have to run?

Any pointers to results in this direction would be appreciated.

Comment: For the first problem: [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and [law of large numbers]. For the other one: [statistical testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).